# Binomial Distribution and Marginal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

Consider $X_{1} = x$ and $n$ a natural number and $p$ between $0$ and $1$

$X_{1}  \sim B(n, p) =  \binom{n}{x} p^{x} q^{n-x}$

$X_{2}$ | $ X_{1} \sim B(X_{1}, p)$

...

$X_{k}$ | $ X_{k-1} \sim B(X_{k-1}, p)$

I am looking for the Marginal Distribution of $X_{k}$. How can I represent  $X_{k}$?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simply look at $X_2$ to start, then

$$\mathbb{P}(X_2=x)=\sum_{y=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X_2=x|X_1=y)\mathbb{P}(X_1=y)$$

If $y<x$, the conditional probability is $0$, thus

$$\mathbb{P}(X_2=x)=\sum_{y=x}^n \mathbb{P}(X_2=x|X_1=y)\mathbb{P}(X_1=y)$$

We can now write

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathbb{P}(X_2=x|X_1=y) & = & {y \choose x} p^x q^{y-x} \\ \mathbb{P}(X_1=y) & = & {n \choose y} p^y q^{n-y}  \end{eqnarray}$$

and thus

$$\mathbb{P}(X_2=x)=\sum_{y=x}^n {y \choose x} p^x q^{y-x} {n \choose y} p^y q^{n-y}$$

We can work out the combinatorial factors and regroup some other factors

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathbb{P}(X_2=x) & = & p^x q^{n-x} \sum_{y=x}^n \frac{n!}{x!(y-x)!(n-y)!} p^y \\ & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^x q^{n-x} \sum_{y=x}^n \frac{(n-x)!}{(y-x)!((n-x)-(y-x))!} p^y \\ & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{2x} q^{n-x} \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{(z)!((n-x)-z)!} p^z \end{eqnarray} $$

In the last step, you recognize with the binomium of Newton $(1+p)^{n-x}$, thus

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathbb{P}(X_2=x) & = & \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{2x} q^{n-x} (1+p)^{n-x}\\ & = & \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{2x} (1-p)^{n-x} (1+p)^{n-x}\\ & = & \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}(p^2)^{x} (1-p^2)^{n-x} \\ \end{eqnarray} $$

This means that $X_2 \sim B(n,p^2)$. I think you can take it from here.

---

**EDIT**: For the induction step, assume $X_{k-1}\sim B(n,p^{k-1})$, then

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=x|X_{k-1}=y) & = & {y \choose x} p^x q^{y-x} \\ \mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}=y) & = & {n \choose y} p^{(k-1)y} (1-p^{k-1})^{n-y}  \end{eqnarray}$$

and thus

$$\mathbb{P}(X_k=x)=\sum_{y=x}^n {y \choose x} p^x q^{y-x} {n \choose y} p^{(k-1)y} (1-p^{k-1})^{n-y}$$

Then work out as before

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathbb{P}(X_k=x) & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^x \sum_{y=x}^n \frac{(n-x)!}{(y-x)!((n-x)-(y-x))!} q^{y-x}p^{(k-1)y} (1-p^{k-1})^{n-y} \\& = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^x \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{z!((n-x)-z)!} q^z p^{(k-1)(z+x)} (1-p^{k-1})^{(n-x)-z} \end{eqnarray} $$

In the last step, I again made the change of variables $z=y-x$. And now I can pull out the factor $p^{(k-1)x}$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathbb{P}(X_k=x) & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{kx} \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{z!((n-x)-z)!} q^z p^{(k-1)z} (1-p^{k-1})^{(n-x)-z} \\ & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{kx} \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{z!((n-x)-z)!} (1-p)^z (p^{k-1})^z (1-p^{k-1})^{(n-x)-z} \\ & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{kx} \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{z!((n-x)-z)!} (1-p)^z (p^{k-1})^z (1-p^{k-1})^{(n-x)-z} \\ & = &\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{kx} \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{z!((n-x)-z)!} (p^{k-1}-p^k)^z (1-p^{k-1})^{(n-x)-z}\end{eqnarray} $$

Note that the last sum is the binomial expansion of

$$(1-p^k)^{n-x}=(1-p^{k-1}+p^{k-1}-p^k)^{n-x}$$

We can therefore rewrite

$$\mathbb{P}(X_k=x) = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}(p^k)^x (1-p^k)^{n-x}$$

which confirms that $X_k \sim B(n,p^k)$. This ends the proof by induction.

Comment: So we can say that $X_{k} \sim B(n,p^{k})$ ?

Comment: No, that's not it. Think about what will happen for $X_3$ now.

Comment: Well, if we $$\mathbb{P}(X_3=x)=\sum_{y=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X_3=x|X_2=y)\mathbb{P}(X_2=y)$$, will we not become p^3 ?

Comment: If the step from $X_1$ to $X_2$ corresponds to squaring the probability $p$, what does it mean for a step from $X_2$ to $X_3$? It's irrelevant what the index is, it will still be a squaring of $p^2$. So, if you square twice in a row, that's $p^4$ and not $p^3$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you. Following that i will become $p^{2^{k-1}}$?

Comment: According to my professor it would be p^k so are you sure?

Comment: Well, all you have to do is work out the recursion for the general case. Assume that $X_k \sim B(n,p^k)$ and compute $X_{k+1}$ the same way I did for the special case from $X_1$ to $X_2$.

Comment: Your professor is right, it is $p^k$, I worked it out quickly on paper.

Comment: I am trying to prove it by induction.. Ist it correct to say that
$$P(X_{k+1}=x)  =  p^x q^{n-x} \sum_{y=x}^n \frac{n!}{x!(y-x)!(n-y)!} p^y  $$

 $$ = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^x q^{n-x} \sum_{y=x}^n \frac{(n-x)!}{(y-x)!((n-x)-(y-x))!} p^y $$
 $$   = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^{(k+1)x} q^{n-x} \sum_{z=0}^{n-x} \frac{(n-x)!}{(z)!((n-x)-z)!} p^z $$

knowing that $ (X_k) \sim B(n,p^k)$

Comment: No, that doesn't seem right. Or at least not complete. I'll update my reply later, but I don't have the time right now.

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: I updated my reply, if you didn't notice.